# mongodb: document with the maximum number of matched targets

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need help to solve the following issue. My collection has a "targets" field.

Each user can have 0 or more targets.

When I run my query I'd like to retrieve the document with the maximum number of matched targets.

Ex:

```
documents=[{
    targets:{
        "cluster":"01",
    }
},{
    targets:{
        "cluster":"01",
        "env":"DC",
        "core":"PO"
    }
},{
    targets:{
        "cluster":"01",
        "env":"DC",
        "core":"PO",
        "platform":"IG"
    }
}];

userTarget={
    "cluster":"01",
    "env":"DC",
    "core":"PO"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking to return the document where the most conditions were met, and possibly not all conditions. The basic process is an `$or` query to return the documents that can match either of the conditions. Then you basically need a statement to calculate *"how many terms"* were met in the document, and return the one that matched the most.

So the combination here is an [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) statement using the intitial results from [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to calculate and then sort the results:

```js
// initial targets object
var userTarget = {
    "cluster":"01",
    "env":"DC",
    "core":"PO"
};

// Convert to $or condition
// and the calcuation condition to match
var orCondition = [],
    scoreCondition = []

Object.keys(userTarget).forEach(function(key) {
    var query = {},
        cond = { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$target." + key, userTarget[key]] },1,0] };

    query["target." + key] = userTarget[key];
    orCondition.push(query);
    scoreCondition.push(cond);
});

// Run aggregation
Model.aggregate(
    [
        // Match with condition
        { "$match": { "$or": orCondition } },

        // Calculate a "score" based on matched fields
        { "$project": {
            "target": 1,
            "score": {
                "$add": scoreCondition
            }
        }},

        // Sort on the greatest "score" (descending)
        { "$sort": { "score": -1 } },

        // Return the first document
        { "$limit": 1 }
    ],
    function(err,result) {
       // check errors

       // Remember that result is an array, even if limitted to one document
       console.log(result[0]);
    }
)
```

So before processing the aggregate statement, we are going to generate the dynamic parts of the pipeline operations based on the input in the `userTarget` object. This would produce an `orCondition` like this:

```js
{ "$match": {
    "$or": [
        { "target.cluster" : "01" },
        { "target.env" : "DC" },
        { "target.core" : "PO" }
    ]
}}
```

And the `scoreCondition` would expand to a coding like this:

```js
            "score": {
                "$add": [
                    { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$target.cluster", "01" ] },1,0] },
                    { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$target.env", "DC" ] },1,0] },
                    { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$target.core", "PO" ] },1,0] },
                ]
            }
```

Those are going to be used in the selection of possible documents and then for counting the terms that could match. In particular the "score" is made by evaluating each condition within the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) ternary operator, and then either attributing a score of `1` where there was a match, or `0` where there was not a match on that field.

If desired, it would be simple to alter the logic to assign a higher "weight" to each field with a different value going towards the score depending on the deemed importance of the match. At any rate, you simply [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) these score results together for each field for the overall "score".

Then it is just a simple matter of applying the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to the returned "score", and then using [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to just return the top document.

It's not super efficient, since even though there is a match for all three conditions the basic question you are asking of the data cannot presume that there is, hence it needs to look at all data where *"at least one"* condition was a match, and then just work out the *"best match"* from those possible results.

Ideally, I would personally run an additional query "first" to see if all three conditions were met, and if not then look for the other cases. That still is two separate queries, and would be different from simply just pushing the "and" conditions for all fields as the first statement in `$or`.

So the preferred implementation I think should be:

1. Look for a document that matches all given field values; if not then
2. Run the either/or on every field and count the condition matches.

That way, if all fields match then the first query is fastest and only needs to fall back to the slower but required implementaion shown in the listing if there was no actual result.